# How to combine the same date and create one section for each date for SwiftData model in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, date, listview, swiftui

This is my SwiftData model. I need to create a section based on each date entry add in my model under that create rows if the dates are same

```
@Model final class Item: Identifiable { 
    var timestamp: Date 
    var duration: String 
}
```

My query don't know how to sort and create section from this.

```
@Query(sort: \\Item.timestamp , order: .forward) private var items: \[Item\]
```

@Model
final class Item: Identifiable {
var timestamp: Date
var duration: String
}

I tried this by adding a date picker when you select date it will give same date entries

```
items.filter { Calendar.current.compare($0.timestamp, to: selectedDate, toGranularity: .day) == .orderedSame }
```

Comment: SwiftData does not have sectioning you have create it yourself as of now. Dictionary grouping is an option but it usually leads to slower performance